# Is that possible for an applet to install another applet or to send APDUs?

Tags: applet, javacard, apdu

Is that possible for a javacard applet to download and install another applet?

Is that possible for an applet to send APDUs (information) to another applet?

If so, can anyone lead me to proper documentations to begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is that possible for a javacard applet to download and install another applet?**

No, that's not possible, there is simply no API for it. In all the examples from Global Platform - which is probably more relevant than the Java Card specifications - the applet data is loaded through APDU commands. There is an `Applet.install` method in the Java Card API of course, but it gets called *by the system* and cannot be used from another applet - not even a security domain, as far as I know.

> **Is that possible for an applet to send APDUs (information) to another applet?**

Yes, you can have one class implement the `Shareable` interface and share it through the [`getShareableInterfaceObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/Applet.html#getShareableInterfaceObject(javacard.framework.AID,%20byte)) method. All Java Card tutorials will include this.

The APDU buffer cannot be shared, but it doesn't need to, you can simply access it through the `APDU` methods. From the API:

> The Java Card runtime environment designates the APDU object as a temporary Java Card runtime environment Entry Point Object (See Runtime Environment Specification, Java Card Platform, Classic Edition, section 6.2.1 for details). A temporary Java Card runtime environment Entry Point Object can be accessed from any applet context. References to these temporary objects cannot be stored in class variables or instance variables or array components.

Please do read tutorials or buy the old but still valid [Java Card technology for Smart Cards](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-cardtm-technology/0201703297/). It's old, but the core principles are still completely valid, and most other basic things can be learned by studying the API.

Comment: Thank you Marteen. You know what I'm doing? updating or installing an applet remotely through internet by sending new applet information encrypted by an asymmetric key which can only be decrypted inside the card and used afterward. I'm searching for a solution for that.

Comment: Well, if anywhere the solution for that should be in the Global Platform. It's a relatively complex subject unfortunately, but it has solutions. I don't think I should give too much information about it though due to past employments.

Comment: I remember reading that book. Thanks for making me feel very old @MaartenBodewes...

Comment: If I remember correctly we're about the same age, so I had the same kind of recollection :)